# Getting draggable marker position (lat,lng) in Google Maps (React)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps API, I am attempting to capture the exact lat and lng of a marker in React, however I am running into some difficulty.

This is my event listener -

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', (e) => {
  console.log(marker.getPosition());
});
```

Browser console  -

```
_.F {lat: function, lng: function}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. Let's find `marker.getPosition` in the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

We see there that the return value for that function is a `LatLng` object. We can navigate to that object in the documentation by clicking on the text:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

And there we see that a `LatLng` object contains `lat()` and `lng()` functions that return the actual values.

So putting it all together, to get the latitude and longitude coordinates:

```
var position = marker.getPosition()
var lat = position.lat()
var lng = position.lng()
```